# Parsing Network Device Inventory in XML Format with Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm new to Python-trying to parse an xml file which contains switch and router inventory.
I have tried this by importing ET and using the below code to just get the first one or two lines of inventory in the xml file:
(I've read the other solutions for parsing xml files on this sites and have tried some of them, even with BeautifulSoup, but have had no luck with how my xml file is structured.).

I can identify the root and child of the root with Python, however, what I'm having trouble with is drilling down and calling the actual data contained under "table_data". Below is a snippet of the xml file, there are about 20 more devices in the file.
In the for loop I've tried 'field name', I have also tried 'field' and 'name' with no results.
Of course, calling other tags within the 'for loop' does not work at this point.
I'd appreciate it if you would point me in the right direction.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('ios_inventory.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for f in root.findall('field'):
    att=f.attrib
    n=att.get('name')
```

Contents of 'ios_inventory.xml'

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="IOS_INVENTORY">
    <table_structure name="Cisco_IOS_Inventory">
        <field Field="Hostname" Type="varchar(100)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="Local_IPs" Type="varchar(5000)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="Local_SVI_IPs" Type="varchar(5000)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="IOS_Image" Type="varchar(200)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="IOSVersion" Type="varchar(200)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="Flash" Type="varchar(200)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <field Field="SerialNo" Type="varchar(2000)" Null="YES" Key="" Extra="" Comment="" />
        <options Name="Cisco_IOS_Inventory" Engine="InnoDB" Version="10" Row_format="Compact" 
        Rows="37" Avg_row_length="442" Data_length="16384" Max_data_length="0" Index_length="0" 
        Data_free="5242880" Create_time="2017-05-31 04:23:01" Collation="latin1_swedish_ci" 
        Create_options="" Comment="" />`
    </table_structure>
    <table_data name="Cisco_IOS_Inventory">
    <row>
        <field name="Hostname">SW2
</field>
        <field name="Local_IPs"></field>
        <field name="Local_SVI_IPs">10.100.x.x</field>
        <field name="IOS_Image">CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M</field>
        <field name="IOSVersion">03.06.10E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)</field>
        <field name="Flash">1621966848 bytes total</field>
        <field name="SerialNo">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="Hostname">SW3
</field>
        <field name="Local_IPs"></field>
        <field name="Local_SVI_IPs">10.100.x.x</field>
        <field name="IOS_Image">CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M</field>
        <field name="IOSVersion">03.06.10E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)</field>
        <field name="Flash">1621966848 bytes total</field>
        <field name="SerialNo">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="Hostname">RTR_2</field>
        <field name="Local_IPs">10.100.x.x | 10.253.x.x</field>
        <field name="Local_SVI_IPs"></field>
        <field name="IOS_Image">X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M</field>
        <field name="IOSVersion">16.4.2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)</field>
        <field name="Flash">6741659648 bytes total</field>
        <field name="SerialNo">XXXXXXXXX</field>
    </row>
```

Thanks Jack. I've pasted the short xml sampl at the bottom. Want to get the output shown as below- with the corresponding values.
Please note: the Local_SVI_IPs can have multiple IP addresses in the xml file.

```
hostname: 
Local_SVI_IPs:
IOS_Image: 
IOSVersion: 
Flash:
SerialNo:



        <field name="Hostname">SW2</field>
        <field name="Local_IPs"></field>
        <field name="Local_SVI_IPs">10.100.x.x</field>
        <field name="IOS_Image">CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M</field>
        <field name="IOSVersion">03.06.10E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)</field>
        <field name="Flash">1621966848 bytes total</field>
        <field name="SerialNo">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</field>
    </row>
```

Comment: First, your xml isn't well formed; please edit with a short, representative xml sample. Second, please indicate your exact expected output from that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your actual xml; but with the one you supplied (note that the xml in the question is still not well formed):

```
from lxml import etree
hosts = """[your xml above, fixed]"""
doc = etree.XML(hosts)
rows  = doc.xpath('//row')
for row in rows:    
        print('hostname: ',row.xpath('field[@name="Hostname"]/text()')[0].strip())
        if len(row.xpath('field[@name="Local_SVI_IPs"]/text()'))>0:
            print('Local_SVI_IPs: ',row.xpath('field[@name="Local_SVI_IPs"]/text()')[0].strip())
        else:
            print('Local_SVI_IPs: NA')
        print('IOS_Image: ',row.xpath('field[@name="IOS_Image"]/text()')[0].strip())
        print('IOSVersion: ',row.xpath('field[@name="IOSVersion"]/text()')[0].strip())
        print('Flash: ',row.xpath('field[@name="Flash"]/text()')[0].strip())
        print('SerialNo: ',row.xpath('field[@name="SerialNo"]/text()')[0].strip())    
        print('-------')
```

Output:

```
hostname:  SW2
Local_SVI_IPs:  10.100.x.x
IOS_Image:  CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M
IOSVersion:  03.06.10E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Flash:  1621966848 bytes total
SerialNo:  xxxxxxxxxxxxx
-------
hostname:  SW3
Local_SVI_IPs:  10.100.x.x
IOS_Image:  CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M
IOSVersion:  03.06.10E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Flash:  1621966848 bytes total
SerialNo:  xxxxxxxxxxxxx
-------
hostname:  RTR_2
Local_SVI_IPs: NA
IOS_Image:  X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M
IOSVersion:  16.4.2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Flash:  6741659648 bytes total
SerialNo:  XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I  will fix the xml file and load the code in the morning.

Comment: The only change I had to make to your code was to add parse to the third line: from doc=etree.XML(hosts)  to etree.parse(hosts). Otherwise it gives me the exact data in the output. Thank you so much! this has saved me hours of work.